# Possible to generate an electromagnetic field from moving an object through a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to generate an electromagnetic field from a stationary rare earth magnet with a hole in it by passing an object through the hole?

By definition, a Lorentz Force is the force on a particle which moves with velocity through an electric field and magnetic field. Would it be some how be possible to instead move a particle with force through a magnetic field to generate an electric field? (Where the magnetic field were not changing with time such as a stationary rare earth magnet with a hole in it)

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood of your description, a stationary magnet with a hole in it can be seen exactly as a coil conducing electricity.

So, the object that passes through the coil, if conductive, will be fired up ([Coil Gun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeRQsoqcO78)). If you stop the object from moving, it will heat up. If it heats up, you'll have an Infra-Red electromagnetic field.

Comment: Sort of. However, in the video, and in the idea of a coil gun, an electromagnetic charge is used via the coil in order to produce a force on an object. What I am talking about is having the coil (or magnet in this case) setup, but off (not generating an electromagnetic field, only a magnetic one), and moving something through the center of it which would interact with the magnetic field to generate an electromagnetic field. Perhaps something which would have drag from the magnetic field which then wind a mini generator causing an electromagnetic field.